# Assigning a value to list by index out of range

Tags: python, list

```
mylist = ["a", "apple", "b", "ball", "c", "cat"]
mylist[6] = "value"
print(mylist)
```

Error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I remember assigning values by index in javascript, it doesn't work in python?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work. Use `append`. Or if you are actually trying to access the 6th element use `5` instead.

Comment: Python's lists are 0-indexed.

Comment: @jamylak I want to add new value in the list, with using append function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python single assignment does not work if the index does not exist. Javascript arrays are *"sparse"*, you can stash a value at any index. Instead, python lists have a defined size, and assignment is only allowed in existing indices.

If you want to add at the end, use `mylist.append(value)`,

Answer (score 14):

Python's lists are 0-indexed. You have 6 elements in your list, so you can index them with anything from `0` to `5`. Attempting to go beyond those bounds will not work with the normal `list` type, but it seems you want to use indexing as implicit list-extension.

For that you want a sparse container, and here's a quick implementation that subclasses list.

```
class SparseList(list):
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        """Overrides list's __setitem__ to extend the list
           if the accessed index is out of bounds."""
        sparsity = index - len(self) + 1
        self.extend([None] * sparsity)
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
```

Use this like this:

```
In [8]: sl = SparseList()

In [9]: print(sl)
[]

In [10]: sl[3] = "hi"

In [11]: print(sl)
[None, None, None, 'hi']
```

And your specific example:

```
In [11]: mylist = SparseList(["a", "apple", "b", "ball", "c", "cat"])

In [12]: print mylist
['a', 'apple', 'b', 'ball', 'c', 'cat']

In [13]: mylist[6] = "value"

In [14]: print mylist
['a', 'apple', 'b', 'ball', 'c', 'cat', 'value']
```

And if you want something a little less self-made, try [`blist`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist)

Comment: Right, so `value` will replace `cat`, but I want to assign a new value at the end (without using append etc..)

Comment: @SiriusKoder - You mean putting a new value in? Python's lists do not work that way. You would have to make your own wrapper class that implements a sparse list (basically creating a list that would have a bunch of `None` values in it.

Comment: @birryree: Is it possible in this way. Use [len] (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) function on the list, decrement the value by 1 (since Python lists are 0-based) and assign a value to the index?

Comment: @jamylak: I think he just wants to assign a value to the last element ie. replace the last element, is it, @SiriusKoder?

Comment: @versimilitude well then he can just use `mylist[-1]`

Comment: @verisimilitude - he wants a sparse list, which allows assignment to any arbitrary position in the list, even if that position doesn't exist yet as a result of `append`ing.

Comment: @SiriusKoder - See my revised answer for a sparse list implementation that subclasses the built in `list` class of Python and allows Javascript-like list behavior.

Comment: Got it. +1 to your suggestions above birrytree :)

Comment: @verisimilitude just to clarify, I want to append not replace.

Comment: For some heavy duty sparse entry work, I would opt to use a dictionary with keys as indexes. This has the advantage of not having to create all the entries in between when accessing an item.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking can be done with SparseList as described by birrye. Or you can always use append. In python dictionary though you can have any indexed assignment say,

```
dic = {}
dic['1'] = 100
dic['2'] = 200
```

So what you can do is write like this,

```
list = {}
i = 1 #Your index
list[str(i)] = value #Your value
```

This might increase the execution time a bit. You will get IndexError exception raised if you reference any unassigned index.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by first creating a list of `None` objects, but it's probably not the best way to do things.

```
mylist = [None] * 10
mylist[0:5] = ["a", "apple", "b", "ball", "c", "cat"]
mylist[6] = "value"
```

Alternatively, you could just append elements to the end of the list.

```
mylist = ["a", "apple", "b", "ball", "c", "cat"]

# create 7th element
mylist += ["value"]

# create 10th element
mylist += [None] * 2 + ["value2"]
```

Comment: You can also slice beyond the range of the list i.e. `mylist[13:13] = [1]`. This causes the assignment to be appended to the end of the list.